# Using a field from a URL for filtering in ListAPIView in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Iam using a generic ListApiView of Django Restframework, the serializer iam using consist of many other serializer(nested serializers). I need to know how I can use the keyword from URL and pass it to the serializer in order for me to filter the result using the keyword in the URL.

For example I have a api view as this

```
class GetList(Generics.ListApiView):
    serializer Class = ABCSerializer
```

I want to pass a value from a URL, to filter some parts of results produced by the serializer. This ABCSerializer is composed of many other nested serializers. I want to filter the result using the Value from URL not like primary key.

In the below example it shows the filter based on username in the URL.

```
url('^purchases/(?P<username>.+)/$', PurchaseList.as_view()),
```

we can write a view that returned a purchase queryset filtered by the username portion of the URL:

```
class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the purchases for
        the user as determined by the username portion of the URL.
        """
        username = self.kwargs['username']
        return Purchase.objects.filter(purchaser__username=username)
```

using the same approach as the above, I want to use a filter a query based on a string that is other than username, and also pass this string to the serializer. and use it as filter in nested serializers.

Thanks

Comment: You can try `filter_backends` and `filterset_fields` in here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/. But maybe need more detail for your question like example.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `DjangoFilterBackend` for filtering on your model's fields.

You can do it by following steps

1. Install Django Filter into your Django application.

   ```
   pip install django-filter
   ```

   Add default filter backend to your `settings.py`

   ```
   REST_FRAMEWORK = {
       'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',)
   }
   ```
2. Enter `filter_backends` property of your view/ viewset that you want filter to be applied.

   ```
   from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

   class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
       ...
       filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
   ```
3. Add list of fields on model to `filterset_fields` property on your view/ viewset for applying filters to those fields.

   ```
   class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
       queryset = Purchase.objects.all()
       serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer
       filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
       filterset_fields = ('category', 'other_field')
   ```

   I hope this would help you to filter on ListAPIViews.

For more details visit [API Guide on Django filter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#api-guide)

For advanced filter use/ visit package [django-rest-framework-filters](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters)

Comment: `filterset_fields ` was crucial for me before the "filter" button pops up on the html api view. Missing from the docs! Also, it seems that you can't give `"__all__"` here.